# Speech Recognition api with Project Oxford

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I downloaded an app from Project oxford site and trying to make it work. So the code works when its given a wav file as input. When trying to make it work with Microphone its not working.

- Ran VS in Admin mode
- Checked Microphone privacy setting
- Modified code in various ways to make it work
- Primary/Secondary key should be working as it works with Wav file but not with microphone.

Here is sample modified code

```
using MicrosoftProjectOxford;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

namespace MicrosoftProjectOxfordExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string m_primaryOrSecondaryKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["primaryKey"];
        private const string LongWaveFile = @"batman.wav";
        private const string ShortWaveFile = @"whatstheweatherlike.wav";
        private string m_filename = null;
        private SpeechRecognitionMode m_recoMode = SpeechRecognitionMode.ShortPhrase;
        private bool m_isMicrophoneReco = true;

        private DataRecognitionClient m_dataClient;
        private MicrophoneRecognitionClient m_micClient;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainWindow"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Intialize();
        }

        private void Intialize()
        {
            if (m_isMicrophoneReco) {

                    m_micClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.CreateMicrophoneClient(m_recoMode, "en-us",m_primaryOrSecondaryKey);
                // Event handlers for speech recognition results
                m_micClient.OnResponseReceived += this.OnResponseReceivedHandler;
                m_micClient.OnPartialResponseReceived += this.OnPartialResponseReceivedHandler;
                m_micClient.OnConversationError += this.OnConversationErrorHandler;
                m_micClient.OnMicrophoneStatus += this.OnMicrophoneStatus;
            }
            else {
                  DataRecognitionClientWithIntent intentDataClient;

                m_dataClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.CreateDataClient(m_recoMode, "en-us",m_primaryOrSecondaryKey);


                // Event handlers for speech recognition results
                m_dataClient.OnResponseReceived += this.OnResponseReceivedHandler;
                m_dataClient.OnPartialResponseReceived += this.OnPartialResponseReceivedHandler;
                m_dataClient.OnConversationError += this.OnConversationErrorHandler;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Click event of the button1 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.editText1.Text = String.Empty;
            this.button1.IsEnabled = false;
            m_micClient.StartMicAndRecognition();

        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            int waitSeconds =  15;

            bool isReceivedResponse = m_micClient.WaitForFinalResponse(waitSeconds * 1000);
            // We are done sending audio.  Final recognition results will arrive in OnResponseReceived event call.
            m_micClient.EndMicAndRecognition();
            this.WriteLine("App Done.");


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Click event of the button2 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool isReceivedResponse = false;

            int waitSeconds = (m_recoMode == SpeechRecognitionMode.LongDictation) ? 200 : 15;

            // sleep until the final result in OnResponseReceived event call, or waitSeconds, whichever is smaller.
            if (null != m_dataClient)
            {
                isReceivedResponse = m_dataClient.WaitForFinalResponse(waitSeconds * 1000);
                this.WriteLine("App Done.");
                this.button1.IsEnabled = false;
                m_dataClient.Dispose();
                m_dataClient = null;
            }

            if (null != m_micClient)
            {
                isReceivedResponse = m_micClient.WaitForFinalResponse(waitSeconds * 1000);
                // We are done sending audio.  Final recognition results will arrive in OnResponseReceived event call.
                m_micClient.EndMicAndRecognition();
                this.WriteLine("App Done.");
                this.button1.IsEnabled = false;
                m_micClient.Dispose();
                m_micClient = null;
            }

            if (!isReceivedResponse)
            {
                this.button1.IsEnabled = false;
                this.WriteLine("{0}: Timed out waiting for conversation response after {1} ms",
                               DateTime.UtcNow, waitSeconds * 1000);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes the line.
        /// </summary>
        void WriteLine()
        {
            this.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes the line.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="format">The format.</param>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
        void WriteLine(string format, params object [] args)
        {
            var formattedStr = string.Format(format, args);
            Trace.WriteLine(formattedStr);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                this.editText1.Text += (formattedStr + "\n");
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Called when a final response is received; 
        /// </summary>
        void OnResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, SpeechResponseEventArgs e)
        {
            bool isFinalDicationMessage = m_recoMode == SpeechRecognitionMode.LongDictation &&
                                          (e.PhraseResponse.RecognitionStatus == RecognitionStatus.EndOfDictation ||
                                           e.PhraseResponse.RecognitionStatus == RecognitionStatus.DictationEndSilenceTimeout);

            if ((m_recoMode == SpeechRecognitionMode.ShortPhrase) || isFinalDicationMessage) {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => {
                    this.button1.IsEnabled = true;
                }));                
            }

            if (m_isMicrophoneReco && ((m_recoMode == SpeechRecognitionMode.ShortPhrase) || isFinalDicationMessage)) {
                // we got the final result, so it we can end the mic reco.  No need to do this
                // for dataReco, since we already called endAudio() on it as soon as we were done
                // sending all the data.
                m_micClient.EndMicAndRecognition();
            }

            if (!isFinalDicationMessage)
            {
                this.WriteLine("********* Final NBEST Results *********");
                for (int i = 0; i < e.PhraseResponse.Results.Length; i++)
                {
                    this.WriteLine("[{0}] Confidence={1} Text=\"{2}\"",
                                   i, e.PhraseResponse.Results[i].Confidence,
                                   e.PhraseResponse.Results[i].DisplayText);
                }
                this.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Called when a final response is received and its intent is parsed 
        /// </summary>
        void OnIntentHandler(object sender, SpeechIntentEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WriteLine("********* Final Intent *********");
            this.WriteLine("{0}", e.Payload);
            this.WriteLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Called when a partial response is received.
        /// </summary>
        void OnPartialResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, PartialSpeechResponseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WriteLine("********* Partial Result *********");
            this.WriteLine("{0}", e.PartialResult);
            this.WriteLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Called when an error is received.
        /// </summary>
        void OnConversationErrorHandler(object sender, SpeechErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) (() => {
                this.button1.IsEnabled = true;
            }));

            this.WriteLine("********* Error Detected *********");
            this.WriteLine("{0}", e.SpeechErrorCode.ToString());
            this.WriteLine("{0}", e.SpeechErrorText);
            this.WriteLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Called when the microphone status has changed.
        /// </summary>
        void OnMicrophoneStatus(object sender, MicrophoneEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (!e.Recording) {
            //    m_micClient.EndMicAndRecognition();
            //    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) (() => {
            //        this.button1.IsEnabled = true;
            //    }));
            //}

            this.WriteLine("********* Microphone status: {0} *********", e.Recording);
            this.WriteLine();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your mic is the default recording device?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I ended up disabling all the recording devices (except my microphone) from Windows Sound Panel to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I had to make sure my microphone's output was mono and not stereo; make sure to check the format of the audio file you are using. Directly from the Project Oxford API Documentation:

The audio file format must meet the following requirements.

- Container:      WAV
- Encoding:       PCM
- Rate:           16K
- Sample Format:  16 bit
- Channels:       Mono

https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c523778daf217c292592